# difference with vvadd and mt-vvadd in riscv benchmarks

Tags: riscv, chisel

In the riscv-test, specifically the benchmarks test. What is the difference between the vvadd and mt-vvadd test??? Both say "This benchmark adds two vectors and writes the results to a third vector. The input data (and reference data) should be generated using the vvadd_gendata.pl perl script and dumped to a file named dataset.h "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mt stands for multi-threaded. You are correct that they will both add two vectors together but the mt-vvadd test will use the available harts to split up the work.